# feature tracking in video frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, pixel

I am new in Image Processing and Computer Vision. I know little bit of Python and OpenCv (still learning). My issue is: "I have a video clip with 100 frames per second and length of video clip is 4 seconds. The first frame has a square shape (square shape item) with in it. In every subsequent frame the square feature displaces by some pixels."
Now i have to calculate the total displacement of the square shape when the video clip reach the last frame.
I have no idea from where i need to start. Any suggestion for tutorial or blog or code snippet will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You could start by google'ing "how to tracking video opencv" and read any of the hundred things that pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having a look at pyimagesearch website. http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in different ways:
*One solution is to track the center (or any other point) of the square. We know that the displacement of square (in one dimension) is equivalent to the displacement of each point of it. Technically tacking a point is very difficult so you can use some math tricks here.

There is a relationship between total volume (in 2d) of all pixels visited by square and the total displacement:
[total displacement  = (volume of all visited pixels)/(volume of the square) ]
to compute the total volume, track the square and use its coordinates.

** another way is trying with union and intersection of squares in different frames

*** you also may try with background subtraction